# How can I parse the int from a String in C#?

Tags: c#, string

I have a string that contains an int. How can I parse the int in C#?

Suppose I have the following strings, which contains an integer:

```
    15 person 
    person 15
    person15
    15person
```

How can I track them, or return `null` if no integer is found in the string?

Comment: What would you want to happen for input of `15per13so14n`, for example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove all non-digits, and parse the string if there is anything left:

```
str = Regex.Replace(str, "\D+", String.Empty);
if (str.Length > 0) {
  int value = Int32.Parse(str);
  // here you can use the value
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Paste this code into a test:

```
public int? ParseAnInt(string s)
{
  var match = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(s, @"\d+");

  if (match.Success)
  {
    int result;
    //still use TryParse to handle integer overflow
    if (int.TryParse(match.Value, out result))
      return result;
  }
  return null;
}

[TestMethod]
public void TestThis()
{
  Assert.AreEqual(15, ParseAnInt("15 person"));
  Assert.AreEqual(15, ParseAnInt("person 15"));
  Assert.AreEqual(15, ParseAnInt("person15"));
  Assert.AreEqual(15, ParseAnInt("15person"));

  Assert.IsNull(ParseAnInt("nonumber"));
}
```

The method returns null is no number is found - it also handles the case where the number causes an integer overflow.

To reduce the chance of an overflow you could instead use `long.TryParse`

Equally if you anticipate multiple groups of digits, and you want to parse each group as a discreet number you could use `Regex.Matches` - which will return an enumerable of all the matches in the input string.

Answer (score 2):

Use something like this :

```
Regex r = new Regex("\d+");
Match m = r.Match(yourinputstring);

if(m.Success)
{
     Dosomethingwiththevalue(m.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since everyone uses Regex to extract the numbers, here's a Linq way to do it:

```
string input = "15person";
string numerics = new string(input.Where(Char.IsDigit).ToArray());
int result = int.Parse(numerics);
```

Just for the sake of completeness, it's probably not overly elegant. Regarding Jaymz' comment, this would return *151314* when *15per13so14n* is passed.

Comment: You can use `input.Where(Char.IsDigit)` to get the digits.

Comment: @Guffa Thanks, I've edited the answer accordingly. This actually came from an extension method I'm using frequently that checks any string for valid/invalid characters, and I just refactored the "valid chars" parameter into "0123456789".

Comment: You don't need to make the lambda expression `c => Char.IsDigit(c)`, you can use just `Char.IsDigit`.